# Convert FileStream.ReadByte() returned int to byte?

Tags: type-conversion, int, byte, filestream

I need to read all raw bytes in a file and then send them in a byte stream. My problem is that FileStream.ReadByte() returns an int. I can't convert it to a byte. For example:

```
FileStream fStream = new FileStream(filePath);
byte readByte = Convert.ToByte(fStream.ReadByte()); // Throws converted value too large for unsigned byte exception!
byteBuffer[index] = readByte; // Need the raw byte for this byte buffer.
```

How do I solve this in C#?

Thanks and have a nice weekend!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[ReadByte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.readbyte%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) returns byte, cast to an Int32, or -1 if the end of the stream has been reached. You get the exception at the end of file when -1 is returned which can't be converted to byte. 
So just check for it, for example

```
var tmp = fStream.ReadByte();
if (tmp == -1)
    // end of file reading
else 
    byteBuffer[index] = Convert.ToByte(tmp);
```